# Vuejs2 - how to use $(this).val()

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to get current value of select option inside vuejs2.

I have this laravel blade code:

```
<select  class='form-control units' @change='units' name='items_quantity_unit_id[]' required>
    @foreach($units as $unit)
        <option  class='form-control' value='{{$unit["id"]}}'>{{$unit['unit_name']}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And i have this vuejs2 code

```
units:function(){
    var unit_id = $(this).val();
    console.log(unit_id);
}
```

Now when i change on select option i get this error:

```
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

so how can i get the value when i change the option inside vuejs2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
units:function(event){
  var unit_id = event.target.value;
  console.log(unit_id);
}
```

But i'd recommend using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components), take a look at the [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) guide.

Comment: how do i pass parameter with units:function(event,extra_parameter)

Comment: `<select @change="units($event, extra_parameter)">` or with v-model : `<select v-model="unit_id" @change="units(unit_id, extra_parameter)`